# Tag is not getting added after successful edit

Tags: support, tags, edits

I'm trying to add pretty relevant **openjdk** tag to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375613/why-is-the-java-11-base-docker-image-so-large-openjdk11-jre-slim) by editing it. From what I can see right now the questions has 4 tags.

Everything seems to be okay, but when I actually hit 'Save Edits' the change is not applied. I've tried several times, no effect. I was able to add '**java**' tag to this question before, but '**openjdk**' tag is getting ignored all the time.

So what's wrong with me or '**openjdk**' tag?

Comment: It's a synoynm of `java` apparently: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms

Comment: @JonClements Oh I see. Thanks for explanation. A bit weird though, but ok. Probably some notification message wouldn't hurt, that tag will not be added, since it's a synonym of an existing tag?